# Current User decorator in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, nestjs

Can anybody tell me why me decorator @GetUser is not working and throw me only `undefined`?

my decorator:

```
export const GetUser = createParamDecorator((ctx: ExecutionContext): UserEntity => {
    const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return req.user;
});
```

my login function:

```
    public async loginUser(data: CredentialsDto): Promise<LoginResponse> {
        const user = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity)
                                    .findOne({
                                        where: {
                                            email: data.email
                                        }});
        
        if(!user){
            throw new HttpException({
                error: 'User',
                message: 'User not found'
            }, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        const isMatch = await compare(data.password, user.password);
        if(!isMatch) {
            throw new HttpException('Invalid credentials', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        const payload: JwtPayload = {
            email: user.email,
            role: user.role,
        };

        const token = await this._authService.signPayload(payload);
        
        user.lastLogin = new Date();
        user.save();

        return {token, user};
    }
```

thanks for any help

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Could you please add some code showing where you use your decorator? As your question is right now, it's near impossible to help you.

Comment: What does the login function have anything to do with what you're asking? Do you have `passport` in use anywhere or do you assign `req.user` yourself? There's not enough to know what you're doing